# How to add AdMob Banner AD in RecyclarView after 5 or 10 CardView using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, admob, firebaseui

I am working on an android app where I am showing some text coming through the firebase database, now I want to show AdMob Banner AD after 5 CardView in the RecyclarView but I am not understand how to do that because I am beginner in Java and Android Programming language. Can anyone help me to do this implementation.

**MY JAVA CODE**

**POJO CLASS**

```
    private String shaData;

    public Model(){

    }

    public Model(String sha) {
        this.shaData = sha;
    }

    public String getShaData() {
        return shaData;
    }

    public void setShaData(String shaData) {
        this.shaData = shaData;
    }
}
```

**MY VIEW HOLDER CLASS**

```
public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView txtShayari;
    public Button copyButton, shareButton, whatsappButton;

    public Holder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        txtShayari = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        copyButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.copyBtn);
        shareButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.shBtn);
        whatsappButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.waBtn);
    }
}
```

**MY MAIN ACTIVITY**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    ImageView imageView;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, Holder> recyclerAdapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = database.getReference("MyQuotes");

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress);

        loadData();
    }

    private void loadData()
    {
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Model>()
                        .setQuery(databaseReference,Model.class)
                        .build();

        recyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, Holder>(options) {

            int AD_TYPE = 0;
            int CONTENT_TYPE = 1;

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final Holder holder, int position, @NonNull final Model model) {

                holder.txtShayari.setText(model.getShaData());
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                holder.copyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)holder.itemView.getContext().getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                        ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, model.getShaData());
                        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);

                        Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.getContext(), "Shayari Copied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                holder.whatsappButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        whatsappIntent.setType("text/plain");
                        whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                        whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, model.getShaData());
                        try {
                            holder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(whatsappIntent);
                        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                            Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.getContext(), "Whatsapp have not been installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

                holder.shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent .setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, model.getShaData());
                        intent.setType("text/plain");
                        intent = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share With");
                        holder.itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public Holder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.item_view,viewGroup,false);
                return new Holder(view);
            }
        };
        recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyclerAdapter.startListening();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
    }

}
```

This is my whole code too fetch text data from the Firebase server and it is working very well, Simply now I am want too show AdMob banner ads after 5 cardviews on the recyclarview, So please anyone guide me.

Comment: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-native-advanced-feed-android/  chek this you can use native ads for put ads in Recycler view

Comment: can you explain ?